# Developing on a remote server an app symfony

Tags: server, symfony6

I work on a symfony app that i elaborate on a remote server.

My friend that developed the same app encounters a timeout when he launches the dev server, and changes the url to the ip adress of the server. While i don't.

Everythings works fine for me. The behavior is strange because when i launch the command

```
symfony server:start --port=8000
```

on my side, the terminal prints the url `localhost:8000`. But if i follow that url, i should visit my local computer not the remote server?

While it works. I am wondering if **vscode** or **sh client** is making sthg on my computer, which it does not to my friend - like changing the host.

It is important to me because i need to get a cookie from a drupal to a symfony app that work together. If i do not have same domain, i cant get that cookie. That is in a development environment. I would like to understand more about this behaviour.

- I checked the host file
- the symfony command
- I've tried changing ports
- switching from my project to his and launching the commmand myself with his config

It always works for me.